# Why is it impossible to move a chrome (webkit) browser full screen window programmatically?

Tags: google-chrome, delphi, winapi, webkit, window

I made a program in Delphi to move windows to another screen/monitor reserving the state, size (if possible) and center the window on the screen if not fullscreen. Especially for borderless windows this is very useful because the easy window hotkeys of Windows do not work properly.

The function is a part of a software suite. I have tested this with fullscreen YouTube videos and works perfectly with mozilla, IE but not with Chrome and Opera (webkit), the window won't move.

Two questions:

1. What's the reason the window won't move?
2. Can I move it with a trick or is trying to a waste of time?

**EDIT:**
*Found out that the chrome window doesn't respond to any message send to this window, for example, restoring, minimize and maximize the window doesn't do anything (tried also other things). Maybe there is something in the code of chrome that avoids it. Maybe someone can confirm this?*

Some code (using Windows API func moveWindow() ):

```
var
 AHandle : Hwnd;
 brCurrent : TBounds; // TBounds = TRect + width and height 
 iCurrDispNum : LongInt;
 iNextDispNum : LongInt;
 brNext       : TBounds;

begin    
........

AHandle:=getForeGroundWindow();
brCurrent:=getWindowBoundsRect( AHandle );
iCurrDispNum:=getDisplayNumFromBoundsRect( brCurrent );
iNextDispNum:=getNextDisplayNum( iCurrDispNum )
brNext:=getBoundsRectOnDisplay( iNextDispNum, brCurrent.width, brCurrent.height, alNone, TRUE );

    .......
// Finally, move the window with WINAPI function, this does not work for chrome and opera fullscreen window, all other window work ok.  
    moveWindow( AHandle, brNext.left, brNext.top, brNext.width, brNext.height, TRUE );

// Find out if window is moved to other screen
if( getDisplayNumFromBoundsRect( getWindowBoundsRect( AHandle )) <> iNextDispNum ) then
 begin
  // Error, window not moved
 end;
```

**You can try it yourself with this piece of code:**

Put a TTimer on a form and paste code below. What does it do? It checks if the foreground window is a chrome window and moves the window 20px to the left. When you maximize a YouTube video in chrome, the window won't move but moveWindow returns TRUE. Relying on the result of moveWindow is useless. NOTICE: This is just a quick example, not a brilliant piece of code.

```
function getWindowClassName( AHandle : hWnd ) : string;
begin
    SetLength( Result, MAX_PATH );
    SetLength( Result, getClassName( AHandle, PChar( Result ), length(Result)));
end;

// Code in a TTimer proc
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
 h : Hwnd;
 r : TRect;

begin
 h:=getForeGroundWindow();
 writeln( getClassName( h ) );
 if( h > 0 ) and ( getClassName( h ) = 'Chrome_WidgetWin_1' ) and ( getWindowRect( h, r )) then
 begin
  inc( r.left, 20 );
  writeln( moveWindow( h, r.left, r.top, r.right-r.left+20, r.bottom-r.top, TRUE ) ); 
 end;
end;
```

PS: You need to turn on "Generate Console Application" at the Project Options to avoid writeln I/O errors.

////////////////////

The properties of the chrome fullscreen window obtained with MS SPY doesn't show something weird is going on:
[image: spyxx window properties of chrome fullscreen window]

Comment: I am aware of different full screen techniques. Perhaps not all work the same way.

Comment: Why not? Why should a maximized borderless window cannot be moved to a next screen? It's smoother (no flicker) to move the window at once in same state instead of restore it first and after this move it. When it is a YouTube video it is impossible to restore it because the window goes back into the webpage. You  must click the video to make it fullscreen again.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Comment: What *"doesn't work properly"* with the Windows keyboard shortcuts? I have no issues moving borderless windows from one display to another, pressing [Win]+[Shift]+[Arrow Left]/[Arrow Right].

Comment: @David Hefferman: Well, I can post all my code but is allot, I don't think it will help to clarify the problem with moveWindow(). getRectOnDisplay() for example, is a function of my library with extended window functions.   Main function is WINAPI moveWindow(), this is not working, also used setWindowPos but doesn't make any difference. Like I explained, only the fullscreen window of chrome/opera/webkit won't move, all other windows work OK.

Comment: Well, your question was closed. So I guess your approach didn't work out. Perhaps consider doing it our way? Also, nobody asked you to post all of your code. That's not what minimal means.

Comment: @IInspectable: On Windows 7 64bit moving a window with the easy window management functionality works but not in all cases, for example with screens with different resolutions, the window is not centered for example. There is also another problem with these functions, a) It must be turn on in the configuration panel and b) It introduces the auto maximize feature when moving a window to the corner of the screen. That's a feature I don't like so turned it off like many others.

Comment: @David Hefferman: I didn't close the question, somebody else did. The problem is about WINAPI moveWindow() that can't move the window. This is the minimal code, is it not clear enough?

Comment: @David Heeferman: What do you mean with: "Doing it our way?"

Comment: It's all explained in the close notice.

Comment: I change the question, add some info and code, better?

Comment: The problem is at moveWindow(), it won't move only these fullscreen webkit windows. Checked all properties with the debugger and these are ok. The question is, why moveWindow won't move these windows because all other windows move ok.

Comment: Well, you managed to get the question reopened, but I would not have voted to reopen. You didn't do what the close said. There isn't a [mcve]. We can't run your program yet. We don't have your code. We have parts. But what if the problem is in the parts we don't have. So I for one won't spend time trying to guess. I do note that the code we see has no error checking. Why not?

Comment: @David Hefferman: Like I said before, I cannot post the whole monitor library, it will be huge and makes no sense at all because the problem is not there, it is working for all other windows! Same system, specs, only other browser. Checked the window rect and it's all fine. How many times do I have to explain this? No error checking? Look at the code, I don't want to rely on  bool that's returned by moveWindow(). I check the rect has changed and check if is on the expected monitor. Because when rect incorrect (wrong destination) the function returns true. WINAPI doesn't tell on which mon.

Comment: You won't post an [mcve], then I'm not interested. Someone else might be.

Comment: @David Hefferman: Especially for you I add some working example. Also, it's shows you that relying on the result of moveWindow doesn't make any sense.

Comment: That isn't complete. I cannot compile it. I'm no longer interested in this. It has consumed large amounts of my time, and you don't seem keen to make it easy for us. I've done this before. I know how to do it.

Comment: @David Hefferman: Have a nice day David. I think you are looking for a complete solution that you can copy? I don't post my library. It's not about my library, it's about moveWindow, you know? Com'on. Create new project and form with a TTimer, create code and paste the code example. Change the project settings and you are ready to rock. If this is not easy, I don't expect any solution from you.

Comment: And when you how to do it, why you don't post an ANSWER instead? I can read Pascal code, it doesn't have to be exactly the same. This silly conversation about a working example is a waste of time when you know how to do it. Post an answer if you know it.